# netty or linux blocking requests , without showing error how to find out what is blocking?

Tags: linux, http, connection, jmeter, netty

i have netty installed on linux (red hat vm ) with 8 cores 64 bit.

```
limit :
cputime      unlimited
filesize     unlimited
datasize     unlimited
stacksize    10240 kbytes
coredumpsize 0 kbytes
memoryuse    unlimited
vmemoryuse   unlimited
descriptors  65535
memorylocked 64 kbytes
maxproc      8192
```

in windows xp , i running Jmeter that invoking 5000 http post requests.
i can only process 3000~ requests each time never over it . 
if i check failed jmeter request im getting this exception:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:518)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:127)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:640)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:284)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:62)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1075)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1064)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:426)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:255)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)





Thread Name: Thread Group 1-4591
Sample Start: 2013-01-01 16:25:05 IST
Load time: 200
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 1689
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 1689
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.BindException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Address already in use: connect

Response headers:


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

on the netty side i dont see any error or exceptions , its just standing and listening . 
if i do :

```
netstat -a | grep ESTABLISHED | grep 8881 | wc -l
```

i see 50 connections that are open ( i think ) . 
when i close netty and run netstate again i have 0 connection open . but i dont know if this related.
my question is how can i detect the way i can't do more requests?

**SOLUTION !

move client to Linux !**

Comment: Looks like your client ran out of ephemeral port or there's some problem with your client environment (Windows)?

Comment: yes the problem is windows , moved the client to linux and problem solved!!!